# Trying to do a conversion of Bin to hex onto swift language

Tags: ios, swift

Could someone see with wrong with this when i submit doesn't seem to show the answer as the label. If anyone could show me how to fix it!

```
import UIKit

class ViewTwo: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var num: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var hex: UILabel!

    @IBAction func binToHex(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    func binToHex(bin : String) -> String { 
        let num = bin.withCString { strtoul($0, nil, 2) }
        let hex = String(num, radix: 16, uppercase: true)
        return hex
    }
}
```

Comment: It is best to post the code directly here.  When you paste it, put four spaces in front of each line and it will be formatted like code.

Comment: Your binToHex method looks fine

Comment: no i mean i wanted to hit get results and so prints to label. i am having trouble to figure that out. @Leo Dabus

Answer (score 0):

Your hex conversion seems to work, but you are not setting the hex result to label in your button target. Set that like this

```
@IBAction func binToHex(_ sender: Any) {
    self.hex.text = binToHex(bin: "1010")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that really helped me.